# XDK IOS build failes

Tags: ios, cordova, build, intel-xdk

I am trying to build a game (phaser) with XDK on Android & IOS.
and when I build for Android it succeeds.

but for IOS it fails without any specific error message or build log link.
I chosen the IOS build in the upper row so I don't think im using a deprecated build option. [image: Cordova hybrid iOS build option]

So this error is what I get when trying to build: [image: Ios build error message without log link]

As you can see, there is no log link that I can click to read the log.
What is going wrong, and is it even trying to build..
I already tried to restart a project and have already did the certificate & provisioning steps multiple times.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem,

Make sure that in the bundle identifier you only use characters and dots (.)
it seems that XDK does not work otherwise and will fail with an unknown error such as above.

make also sure dat you have configured your certificates, identifiers & provisioning profiles are correct. and always upload your project instead of use existing when XDK ask before build process starts.

DO NOT USE tokens like -_)(*&^%$#D@!~`":;><{}[]|/